# How to add a new version of a project to locally deleted repository

Tags: eclipse, git, repository

I am now new to Github. I have a repository setup for a gwt project, both locally and remotely.  Several versions of the project were developed with Eclipse, committed locally and sync with the remote repository.

Accidentally, I deleted the local repository together with the project from Eclipse. I recovered a copy of the project from a separately zip project-archive in Eclipse, and continued with developing a new version of the project within Eclipse, without using any repository (locally or remotely).

Question: How do I add the new app version to the repository as a new version, so that I can have access to the older versions and compare the files? I can clone the remote repository, but what's next?

Answer (score 0):

You could:

- Clone your remote repository to get a local one
- In this new local repository, remove every files (only keep the `.git` directory at the root)
- Copy everything from your new version, to the local repository
- Check the diffs (`git diff`, `gitk --all` or `git gui`), commit what you want and continue working as usual